# Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do this:

```
$("#canvasDiv").mouseover(function() {
    var pageCoords = "( " + e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY + " )";
    var clientCoords = "( " + e.clientX + ", " + e.clientY + " )";
    $(".filler").text("( e.pageX, e.pageY ) : " + pageCoords);
    $(".filler").text("( e.clientX, e.clientY ) : " + clientCoords);
});
```

and in the console I get this:

> `Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined`

I don't understand... I thought `e` is supposed to be a variable that JavaScript has already set...help?

Comment: JavaScript isn't magic - it can only provide variables when you give it parameters to work with. Since it is possible to pass more or less arguments to a function than the function expects to receive, you won't receive an error in this situation.

Comment: It's called `e` and made available idiomatically (i.e. through `function(e)`), but there's nothing special about it as in "that JavaScript already set".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change

```
$("#canvasDiv").mouseover(function() {
```

to

```
$("#canvasDiv").mouseover(function(e) {
```

True, the first parameter to the callback is pre-defined, but in order to use it you must alias it through an argument name. That's why we specify `e` as the argument. In fact, it's not required that the argument name is `e`. This will work too:

```
$('#canvasDiv').mouseover(function( event ) {

});
```

But you must alias the event object through the name `event` in the function callback.

Comment: I was missing e as parameter in my case, that helped.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining a callback function that will be invoked when the mouseover event occurs.
The framework will pass information about the event as the first argument to this function and it is common to name this argument 'e'. But you have to declare it in the function parameters, i.e.

```
$('foo').mouseover(function (e) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
             .....missing e ---- -\/
$("#canvasDiv").mouseover(function(e) {
    var pageCoords = "( " + e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY + " )";
    var clientCoords = "( " + e.clientX + ", " + e.clientY + " )";
    $(".filler").text("( e.pageX, e.pageY ) : " + pageCoords);
    $(".filler").text("( e.clientX, e.clientY ) : " + clientCoords);
});
```