# how to debug angular services in browser

Tags: angularjs

I have created a factory/service in my angular app.

I want to debug it in the browser. Is there a way that I can access its instance and check what is the value of its functions and variables.

The angular scope can be accessed using

```
angular.element(e).scope()
```

Is there a similar way to access factories ?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I believe you can use something like this:

```
angular.element(e).injector().get('serviceName')
```

And since angularjs services are **singletons**, doing this on any *angular.element* will always return the same service instance/object.

Comment: +1 This is great. Debugging becomes a lot easier with this. Adding a link to the angular documentation will improve the utility even further. ref: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element

Comment: Is this still valid? It was working fine before. But now it says `ReferenceError: e is not defined`

Comment: @IvanWang yes, it's still valid. Just tested and it's working. Are you sure the `e` variable is defined and accessible? (could it be a problem like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326351/uncaught-referenceerror-e-is-not-defined)?)

Comment: @bmleite That could be the reason. Would you please tell me how to define `e` in AngularJs?

Comment: @IvanWang `e` represents a local variable containing a reference to the element on which your Angular application (or is it controller?) is defined.  You need to define it with `var e = document.body` or whatever is appropriate for your situation.

Comment: In Chrome, you can select an element in the elements tab and reference it with $0. So you could select your main controller element, use `angular.element($0).injector().get('serviceName')`

Answer (score 8):

Inject your service into any controller and then `console.log(myService);`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/V3EvS/).

Answer (score 6):

Like @bmleite said, you can use:

```
angular.element( {DOM element} ).injector().get('serviceName')
```

You can select the wanted DOM element (use 'Elements' tab on Chrome Developper Tools or 'HTML' tab on Firefox/Firebug) and then use $0 to point on it in the 'Console' tab.

The simplest element to select is the one you have your ngApp directive on it.
The final code is:

```
var myService = angular.element($0).injector().get('serviceName');
```

Then you have access to all his variables and functions:

```
myService.getConfig('dev');
```

Answer (score 4):

Try [ng-inspect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-inspect/cidepfmbgngpdapgncfhpecbdhmnnemf/related?hl=en-US&gl=IN) chrome extension.

$get('serviceName') in console will return the service or factory instance.

Comment: ng-inspect is much higher rated than Angular Batarang

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain about how it inspects *services* as such, but **Angular Batarang** is a great Chrome extension for debugging Angular apps.  Might be helpful.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk

Useful documentation for Batarang:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9c2805/getting-started-with-angularjs-batarang/