# Ajax Doesn't give me anything in the console?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, jconsole

**Updated Question to better reflect the communities support**

Based on community support I have changed the Ajax function to be as such:

```
(function($){   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a').click(function(e){
          var el = $(this).prev('input[type="checkbox"]');
          if(el.is(':checked')){
               el.prop('checked',false);   
          }
          $.ajax({
              url  : "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Aisis-Framework/CoreTheme/AdminPanel/Template/Helper/UncheckPackageThemeHelper.php",
              type : 'GET',
              data : { 'element_name' : el.prop('name') },      
              success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                console.log(data);
              },
              error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
              } 
          });
          e.preventDefault();
        });
    }); 
 })(jQuery);
```

The resulting PHP Class is as such:

```
class CoreTheme_AdminPanel_Template_Helper_UncheckPackageThemeHelper{

    private $_element_name = null;

    public function __construct(){
        if(isset($_GET['element_name'])){
            $this->_element_name = $_GET['element_name'];
            echo $this->_element_name;
        }
    }
}
```

The network tab shows that I have some out put from activating the Jquery which I have shown below:

[image]

The Console is spitting out no errors, yet not echoing the element name. I have read up on the [Jquery Ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and everything I have been doing, thus far, seems to be correct. Yet I am not getting the desired out put.

**Note:** The response tab is empty.... In other words I am not getting a response back.

Comment: Most likely the error handler is happening instead of the success.

Comment: Can some one tell me why I was downcvoted?

Comment: lack of shown research effort maybe? who knows.

Comment: With the error gone, I still don't see an out put. in the console.

Comment: it would work if you pass the parameter or you can just use `event` instead of `e`

Comment: @KyleAdams that means your error handler is being triggered. Since you aren't doing anything on error, then the expected outcome in the event of an error would be no console output.

Comment: Add the error: function(textStatus){} to your ajax call and log the response to see what's going on.

Comment: Some one needs to tell me why this keeps getting down voted. this isnt fair. Im not getting proper feed back on what to change in my question.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall `textStatus` is the second argument, not the first.

Comment: @KevinB Yep. Link to the Docs Kyle. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @KyleAdams i downvoted because you have shown no research effort, I typed **e is not defined** in Google and the first link I got is **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326351/uncaught-referenceerror-e-is-not-defined**

Comment: This could be a reason for the downvotes too: *"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. "* if you had a minimal understanding of how the $.ajax method worked you would know to add an error callback. And the `e` is undefined error is too obvious. It means you haven't defined `e`.

Comment: @KevinB Please see the Updated OP. Also, Does that mean essentially, because I am asking for help on something I don't understand I shouldn't be asking for help? I have read the docs ....

Comment: @KyleAdams change your error to this `error: function( error ){ console.error( error );}`

Comment: @Connor No errors. The console shows me (2) Link to the source and clicking on that link takes me to the console.log(result) line in the script above. can I safely assume it worked based on the new OP and this information?

Comment: Not sure if you missed something on the edit, but that error function is incorrect, you're also not logging anything. Updated my answer just to show the correct handling.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall I was following conor and changed the error to: `error: function( error ){ console.error( error );}`  - still no errors. Ill update the OP to reflect this

Comment: Basically there are only three reasons why the success callback wouldn't get called. One, you set a timeout in the ajax options and the request took longer than the timeout. Two, the statusCode isn't 200. Three, the ajax response isn't in the requested data format. In your case, it's failing because of Three, meaning the problem is server-side. Take ajax out of the equation and just test your php.

Comment: you cant test a get with out actually submitting a form. and I did what answer two suggested. The codes should be: `$_GET["element_name"]`

It works when it's **NOT** a class. But fails when it is ... Not sure why. The class is instantiated in the file with the ajax call...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So I was doing a lot of things wrong. But this is the only way it works, for me - please post your comments if you have better solution.

In the class, I have to do this:

```
class CoreTheme_AdminPanel_Template_Helper_UncheckPackageThemeHelper{

    private $_element_name = null;

    public function __construct(){
        if(isset($_GET["element_name"])){
            $this->_element_name = $_GET["element_name"];
            echo json_encode($this->_element_name);
        }
    }
}

new CoreTheme_AdminPanel_Template_Helper_UncheckPackageThemeHelper();
```

The class **cannot** be instantiated in the .phtml file with the resulting Ajax or the request is never sent back. Also notice the `json_encode` You cannot pass regular variables back to Ajax  - when in a class (I think) - How ever when not in a class it seems to work - clarification is needed.

The Ajax then looks like this:

```
(function($){   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a').click(function(e){
          var el = $(this).prev('input[type="checkbox"]');
          if(el.is(':checked')){
               el.prop('checked',false);   
          }
          $.ajax({
              url  : "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Aisis-Framework/CoreTheme/AdminPanel/Template/Helper/UncheckPackageThemeHelper.php",
              type : 'GET',
              data : { 'element_name' : el.prop('name') },      
              success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                console.log(data);
              },
              error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
              } 
          });
          e.preventDefault();
        });
    }); 
 })(jQuery);
```

The Data that comes back is what I expect: `"aisis_options[package_RelatedPosts]"`

There ar a couple of issues with this answer - One I dont understand why I have to instantiate the class inside the file its written in, and two not sure why I have to encode the response in a class, but not when its just a "script kiddy" file.

Answer (score 7):

You're not passing in the event to your click handler.

Use.

```
$('a').click(function(e){
   // Your code
});

      $.ajax({
          url  : "<?php echo CORETHEME_ADMIN_TEMPLATE_HELPER_URL . 'UncheckPackageThemeHelper.php'; ?>",
          type : 'GET',
          data : { 'element_name' : el.prop('name') },      
          success: function(result) {
            console.log(result)
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
             console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
          } 
      });
```

Comment: that makes sense. And My Ajax?

Comment: Check your network tab to see what response you get when you hit your method. It may work logging now that there's no errors being thrown.

Comment: Still no errors, with your code.  As stated in a previous comments the console has: `(2) Link to resource` clicking that link takes me to the `console.log(result);` in the JS above. Can I safley Assume it's working? oO. It is working - I put a console.log("Test") in success and see that i the console.

Comment: Is your URL properly formed in the ajax call? View the source since you're rendering PHP to print it. Also, I'm not sure if your first data parameter needs the single quotes. Just a bit of debugging :}. Really curious what response your getting back in the network tab though.

Comment: Updated OP to show the client side JS, also there is no response.

Comment: Looks like your query string is correct if you expect it to use aisis_options[package_RelatedPosts]. I can't see the issue. =\

Comment: Trying the answer below your's I get a response. ... Just not the response I want to see

Answer (score 0):

Simplify the situation. Just for a moment, change your AJAX processor file (UncheckPackageThemeHelper.php) to read like this:

**UncheckPackageThemeHelper.php**

```
<?php
    $test = $_POST['element_name'];
    $r = 'PHP received: [' .$test. ']';
    echo $r;
    die();
```

Also, change your AJAX success function to read like this:

```
      success: function(result) {
        alert(result);
      },
```

At least, this will show you that your AJAX is getting through.

Then, start adding things back into your AJAX processor file (one or two at a time) and keep echoing *something* out so that you can discover where the error is happening.

Comment: I get: `PHP received: [] ` So I changed `_POST` to `_GET` - Same thing. also because its a class will I have to instantiate the class (once the issues figured out) in the file with the Ajax?

Comment: I can verify it works with out being in a class - but being in a class it doesn't work.